# Padding strings that contain accents

Tags: c#, string, padding

I'm padding a string that contains accents in it.  However, the final string length is larger due to the accents that it contains.  I guess it has to do with ASCII / Unicode differences, but I haven't figured out the exact reason.

I already tried:
    myString = "San José del Cabo";
    myString.PadRight(' ', 20);

and

```
myString = "San José del Cabo";
string.format("{0,-20}", myString);
```

And the actual result is 21 characters long.

Is there a builtin method in C# that takes into account the string encoding to return the correct final length?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some sample text?

Comment: There is some chance you are looking for [StringInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx) class...

Comment: Edited to provide a string sample

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was someplace else.  I will mark Jeffrey's response as answer, as the StringInfo class is useful in this cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get the length that you're looking for out of [StringInfo.LengthInTextElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.lengthintextelements.aspx). It would probably look something like:

```
var si = new StringInfo(myString);
int length = si.LengthInTextElements;
```